# Get Forbidden error in spring security role based authentication and authorization

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to learn Spring security where I am facing a problem with Role based security.

There are 2 tables **User** and **Role** having **One to Many** realtions.

When I enter username and password in spring default form, **I successfully fetch correct Users deatails through loadUserByUserName() method.** But on screen I get a message like

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
> this as a fallback.
>
> There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403). Forbidden

Only   **@GetMapping("/user")**  method  works properly.

Here is the controller part

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController {
    
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepo;

    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepo;
    
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')")
    @PostMapping("/add")
 
    public String addUserByAdmin(@RequestBody User user)
    {
        user.getRoles().forEach(role -> role.setUser(user));
        userRepo.save(user);
        return "User added Successfully";
    }

        @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')")
        @GetMapping("/process")
        public String process()
        {
            return "Processing....";
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/user")
        public String users()            // This code is working properly
        {
            System.out.println("U r in user area's");
            return "User's space";
        }
}
```

Configuration part

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UserRepository.class)

public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)throws Exception
    {
       http.csrf().disable();
       http.authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers("/admin/**").authenticated()
           .anyRequest().permitAll()
           .and()
           .formLogin().permitAll(); 
    }
}
```

Service part

```
@Service
public class CustomeUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService
{
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
       
        User u = userRepo.findByName(username);
        
        CustomeUserDetails cUserDetails = new CustomeUserDetails();

        if(u == null)
        {
            throw new  UsernameNotFoundException("User "+username +"not found");
        }
        else
        {
            cUserDetails.setUser(u);
        }
        return cUserDetails;
    }
        
}
```

Where am I wrong ?
What if I want to add one more URL which does not require any authnetication and authorization , how to add it ?

Comment: You have annotated your Controller endpoints with `@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')")` meaning that only users with the role ADMIN can access the endpoints. If you access them with a user that does not have the role ADMIN then you will get a Forbidden response. Are you using a user with the role ADMIN?

Comment: @ Eleftheria Stein-Kousathana  Yes, I am trying those users who has role of ADMIN.

Comment: In that case it's possible the roles are not being associated to the user correctly. To try and debug this issue you can add `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()` to your "/user" endpoint and print the output. This will show which authorities/roles the user has and from there it may be clear why the framework think the user is not an ADMIN.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use "ROLE_ADMIN" instead of "ADMIN". The "ROLE_ADMIN" key can be saved in the database and turned into Collection. Below how I did.

---

CLASS THAT IMPLEMENTS USERDETAILS

```
public class UsuarioSS implements LdapUserDetails {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1164806375870272028L;
private String cdusuariorede;
private Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

public UsuarioSS() {

}

public UsuarioSS(String cdusuariorede,List<Perfil> perfis) {
    super();
    this.cdusuariorede = cdusuariorede;
    this.authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    for (Perfil perfil : perfis) {
        this.authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(perfil.toString()));
    }
}

public String getId() {
    return cdusuariorede;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return authorities;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return cdusuariorede;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}

public boolean hasRole(String springSecurityKey) {
    return getAuthorities().contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(springSecurityKey));
}


@Override
public void eraseCredentials() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

@Override
public String getDn() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

---

ENUM THAT REPRESENTS MY USER PROFILES (AUTHORITHYES)

```
public enum Perfil {
ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_DEFAULT
```

}

---

A AUTHORIZATION FILTER

```
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

private JWTUtil jwtUtil;
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, JWTUtil jwtUtil,
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
    super(authenticationManager);
    this.jwtUtil = jwtUtil;
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    if (header != null && header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = getAuthentication(header.substring(7));
        if (auth != null) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        }
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(String token) {
    if (jwtUtil.tokenValido(token)) {
        String login = jwtUtil.getLogin(token);
        UserDetails usuario = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(login);
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(usuario, null, usuario.getAuthorities());
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

---

MY CONTROLLER

```
@RestController
```

@RequestMapping(value = "/parte")
public class ParteController {

```
@Autowired
private ParteService service;

@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@GetMapping("/partes_demandadas_por_processo")
public ResponseEntity<List<TpPartesProcessoDto>> getPartesPorNuprocesso(
        @RequestParam(name = "processo",required = true)
        @Length(max = 15,min = 15,message = "O campo processo deve possuir 15 caracteres.")         
        String processo
        ) throws SQLException{
    List<TpPartesProcessoDto> partes = service.getPartesdoProcessoPorNuprocesso(processo);      
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(partes);
}
```

}